# How to change the property "default_encoding" of Sublime Text(Version 3.1.1, Build 3176) from "UTF-8" to "ISO-8859-1"?

Tags: windows-10, php, encoding, sublime-text-3, utf-8

I'm a PHP Developer by profession.

I'm using Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System on my laptop.

I've installed Sublime Text(Version 3.1.1, Build 3176) on my machine.

I checked for default character-encoding into file **C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default\Preferences.sublime-settings**

and I found

```
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
```

Now, I want to change it to **"ISO-8859-1"**. I even tried to edit this file but I couldn't. The file is not editable.

So, asking for help from you great people.

Please help me out.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On menubar, choose `Preferences -> Settings` and change the `Preferences.sublime-settings -- User` file like image below:

[image: guide]

Restart Sublime Text after saving settings.

NOTE: If opened file is already in encoding other than the default, Sublime Text will continue to using that encoding.

Comment: I tried making the said change "default_encoding": "ISO-8859-1" in the file "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User" but still it doesn't work. It's taking the default value "default_encoding": "UTF-8" only. Why so?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. But, I'm getting some strange result now. I added  "default_encoding": "ISO-8859-1" in the file "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User" and checked the set encoding using built-in PHP function mb_detect_encoding("str"); but surprisingly instead of getting "ISO-8859-1" as a output result I got "ASCII". Why so?

Comment: You need to specify encoding detection order in `mb_detect_encoding` where "ISO-8859-1" is detected first, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298639/mb-detect-encoding-detects-ascii-as-utf-8).